# Automatically turn a new created tkinter notebook tab into the active tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing my own text editor in Python. When I open files or create a new file it is opened in a new tab, but the new tab never is the active tab.

Is there anything I can do to make the new tab the active tab without manually selecting it in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notebook widget has a method named `select` which will make the given notebook tab active.

This is documented in the official ttk documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.select

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed :D